# how to set download headers to avoid client windows defender blocking javascript files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just tried to download a javascript file and Windows Defender blocked and removed it.

In the server the http headers are set and looks like

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
res.write(data);
res.end();
```

I see this being possible in the jQuery site for example (http://jquery.com/download/) but I see also that other libraries opted by redirecting to a plain text page.

Is there something wrong with my headers? is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you use Express then use Express `sendFile` (http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) and just set the `Content-Disposition` header. Tested and works in latest Chrome and IE11.

```
var file = '/absolute/path/to/file/app.js';
var options = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=foo.js'
    }
};
res.sendFile(file, options);
```

`sendFile` will set the rest of the headers like `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` itself.
BTW, when it comes to JQuery-s download links, they use `download` attribute for the links - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download. But the problem with the `download` attribute seems to be that it's not supported by all major browsers - http://caniuse.com/#search=download

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I noticed the `<a download="">`, that is one idea. What I am curious is if the headers make a difference in the way Windows Defender handles the file.I also used the same header as you suggested, what would `.sendFile` make different?

Comment: @Sergio It's a good question. I did not spot any unusual headers for the JQuery download. Maybe Windows Defender just considers anything suspicious that either is not downloaded over HTTPS or not in some WD trusted domain list? What about the final headers of your attempt? What were they? 
I was testing with ``curl`` to dump headers and data ``curl -i -k https://mytestsite.com/getmyjsfile | head -n 17``

Comment: The file I'm sending is compiled live, so I can't _curl_ it. You can check here: http://mootools.net/core. About the https the jQuery file is not http either. Hmmm... this really makes me curious...

Comment: Sure is interesting, let us know when you find something out.